# How can I determine the height of a bounding box to extract glyphs from a font image?

Tags: python, c, graphics, fonts

I have a tall, narrow, image that has a printable characters (ASCII 32 to 126), one per row, exported from GIMP as a 'c' file:  I'm using this to build 1 bit-per-pixel font structures for an embedded system.

```
/* GIMP RGB C-Source image dump (font.c) */

static const struct {
  unsigned int       width;
  unsigned int       height;
  unsigned int       bytes_per_pixel; /* 3:RGB, 4:RGBA */
  unsigned char      pixel_data[32 * 2400 * 3 + 1];
} gimp_image = {
  32, 2400, 3,
  "\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377"
...
```

I would like to figure out 3 parameters that describe, the line height, space between lines and a starting row offset.

I've written code that tells me which rows in the image are blank:

```
#include "font.c"

#include <stdio.h>

struct image_attributes {
    unsigned int width, height, stride;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const struct image_attributes * const ia = (const struct image_attributes *)&gimp_image;
    unsigned int line_number, last_line, min_seperation;
    int last_state;

    min_seperation = UINT_MAX;

    for (line_number = 0; line_number < ia->height; line_number++) {
            const unsigned char * data;
            unsigned int line_width;
            int new_state;
            size_t index = line_number * ia->stride * ia->width;

            for (data = gimp_image.pixel_data + index, line_width = 0; *data && line_width < ia->width; line_width++, data += ia->stride) {
            }
            new_state = line_width < ia->width;
            if (!line_number) {
                    last_state = new_state ^ 1;
                    last_line = line_number;
            }

            if (last_state != new_state) {
                    if (!new_state) {
                            printf("%4d - ", line_number);
                    } else {
                            unsigned seperation = line_number - last_line;
                            printf("%4d = %d\n", line_number, seperation);
                            if (min_seperation > seperation) {
                                    min_seperation = seperation;
                            }
                    }
                    last_line = line_number;
            }
            last_state = new_state;
    }

    printf("%4d = %d\n", line_number, line_number - last_line);

    printf("\nMinimum Seperation = %d\n", min_seperation);
    return 0;
}
```

With that, I'm trying to figure out what my algorithm will be.  I'm going to start by providing the line height (between two similar glyphs seperated by one row), but I'd like to imagine that there would be a way to do this with out needing that information a priori.

An idea I'm considering is looking at common divisors between the successive blocks of blank lines. I'm thinking this may lead to a voting mechanism whereby the likeliest line height could be determined, and from there it becomes an exercise in aliasing over the blank line data to find the best fit.

Thoughts on what might be a successful approach would be appreciated: and I'm only limited to what I use on the Linux command line (i.e. 'c', Python, Perl, etc.)

Comment: This kind of feels like it might be an off topic question; After all, if all you have is glyph boxes, then the *font* metrics are "what you decide", not what anyone else can tell you. Line height is not determined by glyphs but by you as font designer, and line *spacing* results from line *height* so that's not really a separate thing. Start row offset isn't even font related, that's a typesetting choice. Right now it doesn't feel like there's an actual programming question here, more a "what do you guys think?" question, which would be off topic for Stackoverfow.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I'm not designing the fonts. I'm letting the OS generate them for me, unaliasing them in a image program and then scanning them at a fixed size for use in an embedded system.  The line height is an artifact of how the program generating them is laying them out and although I can measure it, its tedious.  Perhaps you missed the title of the post, its ... a question.

Comment: I saw the title of the post, and it is not the question, that's just the title. A title is a summary, and the post is supposed to contain the actual question with all the details. Your post explains you have a C file that contains glyphs, no details on how they're laid out, with a mention that you want to do something, code that does something else, and a note saying you don't know what your algorithm will be yet. At that point the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) are no longer being followed, and you need to revise your post before it works as a question on SO.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I didn't expect that my cunning of hiding the question in the title would be so confusing.  And perhaps I should have hid the description of the image file somewhere in the middle of the post rather than putting it in the first sentence.  I apologize too, that the code I provided shows how I'm detecting blank lines, which foolishly, I thought would be related to how I would determine the height of the glpyhs.

Comment: sarcasm notwithstanding, the concept has always been and still is "imagine you're asking a busy colleague" - yes, I'm sure all the information was there in some form or other, but not in an immediately obvious way. Showing a wall of code that does *exactly* what you need is great, but not if someone has to first carefully read through it to figure that out. That's time that will get spent leaving a comment to ask for improvement, closing the question, opening another, and answering that instead.